# MvvmLight Good Practice : Show a Form by a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm a fresher with WPF, MVVM. Now, I have been investigating MVVM Light. I got some confused. I appreciate any help from all of you. Thanks in advance for taking a look at this post.

1. Can we absolutely remove code behind of View (such as: Invoking InitializeComponent() somewhere inside .xaml --> Does not need view.xaml.cs anymore in some simple case).
2. I have many views insight my project, how many locator is necessary?
   I intend to make separate locator for each view. And I wonder that if I register all locators in app.xml, are all of views initialized and registered right after user run the application? If Yes, Is it not good for performance?
3. Main question:
   I have a scenario:
   I have many forms: such as :

   1. MainForm: which is the 1st form invoked by application.
   2. ImportForm: which is invoked when User click Import (from MainForm)

Assumption that: I did finish all stuff related to binding (such as button Import --> RelayCommand(OnImport))
What is the best practice for me to implement this scenario?
1. Just implement to init and show ImportForm like below:

```
public void OnImport()
{
   ImportForm importForm = new ImportForm();
   importForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

It's simple, but I wonder if this way follow the MVVM's paradigm?

1. So, I did some researching and do another way like:

   public void OnImport()
   {
      //// Just send message
      Messenger.Default.Send(
         new NotificationMessage(this, "OnImport"));
   }

In Code Behind: MainForm.xaml.cs

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (nm) =>
        {
           if (nm.Sender == this.DataContext)
           {    
                if (nm.Notification == "OnImport")
                {  
                    ImportForm importForm = new ImportForm();
                    importForm.ShowDialog();
                }
           }
        });
    }
```

By this way, I must write some code inside code behind --> Is it a problem?

Both above solutions can finish mentioned scenario correctly, but I confused which one is better or is there any actually right solution out there?

Thanks again for your patience with the long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you cannot. `InitializeComponent()` paints UI on the screen. The purpose of MVVM is to separate logic that does not related to View and store it in a ViewModel. It does not tend or aim to remove code-behind.
2. It depends on you. You can create one Locator for all ViewModels or one Locator per one ViewModel. Anyway, I found that Locator does not scale well and hard to manage in a larger project. It creates dependency between View, Locators and ViewModels. I personal prefer to use DI framework instead of Locator even if it is a small project.
3. You can do both, depends on your requirement. **(a)** If clicking the button on the main form does nothing more than show a dialog then I would use `Click` event because it is View related. It has nothing to do with any logic, so keep it in the code behind is the best solution for me. **(b)** By the way, if clicking the button does something, for example, connect to a database then show a dialog if a condition is true. In this case, I would use Messenger to keep View and ViewModel separate from each other.